# Can I create struts 1.3 <html:text> using javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, html, struts, struts-1

Normally I create html text dynamically using javascript. See sample

```
 var element1 = document.createElement("input");
 element1.type = "text";
 element1.name = "txtbox[]";
 element1.className = "textfield"
 element1.size = "15"
 element1.value = "something"
 cell2.appendChild(element1);
```

But my problem is create struts 1.3 text field dynamically using javascript.I try this but not ok especially elements.value instead of Struts 1.3 property attribute.Is it possible to create struts 1.3 text field using javascript not jquery?

Comment: The `<html:text>` tag will be translated into the `<input>` tag.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by that. You can create the equivalent, simply render in JS the same thing the tag library would render--it's all just HTML eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Struts tags have to be processed on the server before it is sent back to the client machine browser as HTML. JavaScript can only manipulate HTML tags on the client Side.